# Sessões em JS ou jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Existe alguma forma de utilizar sessões em js ou jquery? Gostaria de fazer algo parecido como as sessões do php.

Comment: Pelo que sei não é possível. Javascript é client-side. Sessão é acessada server-side. Posso estar errado e existir uma forma, por isso deixo em comentário. Só se você montar algum script do lado do servidor com os valores da sessão e mandar para o cliente. Mas diretamente acredito não ser possível.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não há maneira segura de fazer isso no lado do cliente.

Podes criar um [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) mas é uma ferramenta limitada e insegura. O Cookie permite uma string com `chaves->valores` mas pode ser modificada pelo usuário ou outras aplicações.

Podes também usar a API Localstorage que é uma API relativamente nova:

```
localStorage.setItem('lastname','Smith'); // gravar
Storage.removeItem('lastname');           // apagar a entrada "lastname"
Storage.clear();                          // apagar tudo o que está no local storage
alert(localStorage.getItem('lastname'));
```

e dessa maneira guardar dados. Mas é também insegura uma vez que o usuário ou outra aplicação pode mudar esse conteúdo.

Podes ler mais sobre [a API aqui (link)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

Comment: e pra finalizar esse localStorage, ou seja, limpar os dados?

Comment: @Furlan juntei mais info

Comment: obrigado @Sergio

Comment: Poderia também usar `sessionStorage`, para sessão efetivamente :P

Answer (score 4):

Há várias formas de manter informações no JS:

- [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#Example): a forma mais antiga e comum. Fácil de setar uma variável, mas exige um pouco de código extra para obter ou remover. Possui limite de espaço e é enviado junto nas requisições ao servidor. É através dos cookies que o PHP mantém o id da sessão do usuário.
- [WebStorage](http://zenorocha.com/html5-local-storage/): introduzida com o HTML5. Possui um limite de armazenamento bem maior que os cookies, além de uma interface mais simples para utilização. É subdividida em dois tipos: **sessionStorage** (mantém os dados apenas para a janela onde foi criada e é perdida quando a mesma é fechada) e **localStorage** (mantém os dados para todas as janelas e não possui data de expiração, só sendo removida por código ou diretamente pelo usuário).
- [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/IndexedDB): utilizada principalmente para armazenamento de dados em maior quantidade. Não possui limite de armazenamento, mas alguns navegadores pedem pela permissão do usuário após atingir certa quantidade (normalmente 50Mb). Funciona de forma assíncrona, um benefício para a performance da aplicação e um complicador para a codificação, embora com js já nos acostumamos com o assíncronismo. Para facilitar na codificação, você pode utilizar um framework, como por exemplo, o [pouchDB](http://pouchdb.com/).
- [WebSQL](https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/02/using-websql-instead-local-storage-web-app/):  funciona como um banco de dados SQL. É a especificação anterior ao IndexedDB e não é mais mantida pela W3C.

Para o seu caso, acredito que a melhor alterativa seja utilizar o localStorage, mas cabe a você avaliar as necessidades da aplicação.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar `Cookies` se sua aplicação não for armazer muita informação além do fato de que você deve dar uma atenção em especial para a segurança e a forma com que você vai armazenar estas informações, já que utilizando Cookies os dados ficam no lado do cliente e por este verificar e validar os dados a cada requisição nunca é demais.

Como alternativa você também pode utilizar `localStorage` que também armazena os dados no lado do cliente e oferece mais vantagens, como espaço de armazenamento maior, não possui data de expiração e uma API extremamente simples de ser utilizada.

**Observação:** As SESSION'S do PHP são armazenas em uma pasta **NO SERVIDOR** definida no `php.ini`, porém para o PHP identificar a SESSION ele utiliza um `session-id` que é armazenado em um `cookie` e algumas vezes é encontrado nas url's de algumas aplicações (normalmente encontrado como paramentro chamado PHPSESSID).

Você pode verificar este comportamento utilizando o Google Chrome e procurando na aba Resources em algum site que utilize sessions.