# Voltar onde ia (VídeoClube)

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Olá, eu estou a criar um mini vídeo clube, e eu queria implementar um sistema que se o usuário estiver a ver um filme e se ele fechar a página e voltar a entrar, tenha um botão para continuar onde parou (tal como também existe na NETFLIX) mas não sei como guardar o momento onde o usuário estava antes de fechar. Estou a fazer isto em PHP, JavaScript(JQUERY), HTML (O player do filme é com a tag vídeo do HTML5)

Comment: Leia aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54941/sess%C3%B5es-em-js-ou-jquery/54945#54945 e aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/19384/diferen%C3%A7as-entre-localstorage-vs-sessionstorage/19387#19387